# Javafx - Pseudoclass inside a Pseudoclass

Tags: javafx

I have a pratical problem where there is an arrow image which is either enabled or disabled, I toggled between two different images for both the cases. When the arrow is active i set a pseudoclass that changes the image to a blue one and when it is disabled, the image is grey

css snippet that does it :

```
#navigateLeftImage:enabled
{
    -fx-image:url("images/left-arrow.png");
}
```

I enable the state of the pseudoclass upon some condition.

Now, one more thing that is needed is when i hover upon the enabled image, it should scale up that can be achieved by css selector :hover, but i only want it to scale up when its image is the enabled one.

If i could nest pseudoclass inside a pseudoclass, I would do something like this

```
#navigateLeftImage:enabled
{
    -fx-image:url("images/left-arrow.png");
    #navigateLeftImage:hover
    {
      //css to scale
    }
}
```

I know that i can add a handler to hover and then remove it when the image is the disabled one, but I would resort to it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS does not allow you to put a rule inside another rule. You could use multiple rules though and select use a selector that only applies, if both pseudoclasses are present:

```css
#navigateLeftImage:enabled
{
    -fx-image: url("images/left-arrow.png");
}

#navigateLeftImage:hover:enabled
{
  //css to scale
}
```